# Silverlight - Printing

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that has a DataGrid. I need to print the selected items in the DataGrid. However, I do not want to use a WritableBitmap. Is there a way for me to pass just those items to either a WCF Service or a .aspx page and render HTML that will prompt the user to print? If so, how?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Silverlight 4, you could use the printing API, but I guess you would not ask this question in this case.

In Silverlight 3, I think you have to resort to some kind of hack, where you SL code calls a JavaScript function, giving it the selected data in some format. This function could open a new window where the data is re-displayed in a print-friendly format and then printed.

I mention a new window, because I guess the window hosting the SL content already has some content that is unrelated to the data to print.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to SL4:

1. Create a WCF service that:

   - takes in an XML blob
   - renders it as PDF (one way to do that is to use FO)
   - stores it in some temp area with unique id
   - returns the id to the client
2. Create an .aspx page that:

   - takes in an id of a PDF file returned by WCF service
   - streams the generated  PDF to the client (with proper Content-Type)
3. SL client:

   - invokes WCF service and gets the id of the generated PDF file
   - constructs the URL of the generated PDF file
   - uses any of JavaScript tricks to popup that URL in the browser (one way is to have a hidden IFRAME and set its source to the URL)

Comment: > renders it as PDF (one way to do that is to use `FO`) what is `FO`?